# greenplum database "relation does not exist"

Tags: database-administration, greenplum

I am getting "relation does not exist" error while trying to truncate a particular table.The table actually exists in the database.
Also when I click on this table in pg admin I get the warning for vacuum.
Are these things related.?

------ Adding few more details----
Truncate statement is called within a greenplum function. This job truncates and load the table on a daily basis(This table is queried in reports)The issue pops up once in a while and if we go and restart the same job again after few minutes it succeeds.

Comment: no it is not related

Comment: It could be a search_path issue.  Are you including the schema name in the drop table statement?  If not, try drop table schema.table cascade;

Comment: Yea schema name is included in the truncate statement. One thing that confuses me is that after a while if I rerun the same query again, it succeeds( This is a table in production and is used by reports).

Comment: Are you dropping the table ever in the process or just using truncate?

Comment: Just truncate and load.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do the below select * from schemaname.tablename limit 10; If you don't use the schema name then you have to set the search path as below and then run your select

set search_path=schemaname;